# Routing/Config errors when upgrading to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

I just installed Ruby 2 and Rails 4, and I created a new project. I made a devise user, and then I went to run the server. I got the error

```
/Users/michaeldunnegan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007f85ac132458 @paths=["/Users/michaeldunnegan/projects/SoundShare/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007f85ac188e48>]> (RuntimeError)
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do. Configuration is pretty weird to me. I think the error might be in my path, whatever that is, but I can't be sure.

My `rvm current` looks like: `ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails-4.0.0`, if that's relevant

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with rails 4 and devise.

Please see the [rails issue on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10559)